# Does NestJs support Rate limiting for WebSocket Gateway?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to figure out how to add Rate limiting feature for WebSocket connection in my NestJS application.

I looked the middleware example about rate limiting using `express-rate-limit` module but that seem to be for express app using HTTP protocol. Correct me if I am wrong.
Here is the link I reviewed. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My original question was not clear enough. I was looking for rate limiting of data consumed per WebSocket connection. So with a bit more research on this, it turns out that NestJs Framework doesn't provide this level of rate limiting even though we can get http request level rate limiting with `express-rate-limit` middleware.

I will need to consider a leaky-bucket algorithm to implement the rate limiting of data per WebSocket connection level.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets don't work on their own; They need to be upgraded from HTTP first.

That means, it's safe to use `express-rate-limit` as a middleware (before you upgrade the connection).